# Streaming movies on iOS, anyone got this working?

Tags: ios8, autolayout, vuforia

I'm trying to support external movies in the VideoPlayback example. You (supposedly) can do this by looking for EXAMPLE_CODE_REMOTE_FILE and changing the bool, so I did that.

Everything works until I try to play the video. I can see it loading into the player but when it appears the screen remains black - although I can hear sound.

This is accompanied with this block of output in the log:

```
2014-10-14 09:12:50.904 MARL_Adhoc[578:145994] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f08b0 H:|-(34)-[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x191d7180 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0920 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0950 H:[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50]-(34)-[UIView:0x191d75d0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f08e0 UIView:0x191d75d0.right == _UIBackdropView:0x191d6890.right - 34>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191d7bf0 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x191d6890]   (Names: '|':MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x191d6650 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191d7c60 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x191d6890]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x191d6650 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17a7eea0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x191d7180.midX == _UIBackdropView:0x191d6890.midX>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17a7eed0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x191d7180.width == _UIBackdropView:0x191d6890.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x191ebfd0 h=-&- v=-&- MPSwipableView:0x17a90350.width == MPMovieView:0x1912deb0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191ec300 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[MPMovieView:0x1912deb0(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17a78ef0 h=-&- v=-&- MPVideoContainerView:0x1912cb30.width == MPSwipableView:0x17a90350.width - 320>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x191ea8b0 h=-&- v=-&- MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView:0x191d6650.width == MPVideoContainerView:0x1912cb30.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0920 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50](LTR)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Ok, great. The thing is, UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints doesn't appear anywhere in my code, or as far as I can tell, Vuforia (should it? or is this saying something else?). I can't find any of the constraints or layout methods being called anywhere in visible code. Nor does it appear I have any in the interface builder either.

Has anyone got full-screen playback working on iOS7/8?

Comment: having same issues by my playback is workin' cuz I am not using Autolayouts. In my case the progressbar disappears from screen and only comes back when app is rotated.

Comment: well if turning off autolayout does the trick, may I ask how you did that in your app?

Comment: well the app is an enterprise one and doesn't use Autolayouts at all. But adding the movieplayer to subview results in constraints clash.

Comment: Interesting. Ok let me look at the whole auto layout thing and see if I can find a global switch or something.

Comment: Ok I did manage to turn off the autolayout in this view. Still no video though! I do hear the sound, just no video.

Answer (score 1):

### this fixed it for me:

1. change MPMoviePlayerController to MPMoviePlayerViewController
2. after initializing the MPMoviePlayerViewController:
       viewController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

Comment: Hey Dries, where do I do the first of those two changes? In the storyboard or somewhere in code?

Comment: @Maury how did you initialised your movieplayer? instead of initialising a MPMoviePlayerController instantiate a MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: Sorry Dries, just got a chance to play with this now. If you are referring to the two instances in VideoPlayerHelper.h and .mm, I cannot make the change you suggest; when the app attempts to trigger playing, it gets sent methods that are part of MPMoviePlayerController, not MPMoviePlayerViewController. Do you not get a bunch of compiler warnings when you build?